# (NetLogo: re-) transformation of turtle xcor/ycor to real-world coords

Tags: gis, transformation, netlogo, projection

I have a well functioning NetLogo model of pedestrians in a generic, urban environment loaded from shapefiles - including projection/transformation (See selected code lines below).

How do I export the xcor's and ycors of turtles to text files, projected/transformed into the original projection system?

Thanks in advance

code examples...

```
gis:load-coordinate-system (word "../data/testLines_2.prj") 
set ODLines gis:load-dataset "../data/testLines_2.shp" 
setUpEnvelopeExtented ODLines 10
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use `gis:store-dataset dataset file`

You need two steps :

1. create a dataset with your agents
2. export your dataset in

You can use something like

```
to export-turtles
  gis:set-world-envelope [-90 90 -90 90 ]
  gis:store-dataset gis:turtle-dataset turtles "bugs"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Thanks Delaye. 
I probably need to be a little more explicit:
What I need is at every tick of my model to export the locations (and more) of every turtle.

file-open "locations.txt"
to go
  ask turtles
    [ file-write xcor file-write ycor ]
end
file-close

But instead of x- and ycor (which I believe are in netlogo space) I need them to be projected into the current GIS-system of the model (as per my load-coordinatesystem primitive).