# NetLogo GIS extension : how to have right xcor and ycor from turtles

Tags: gis, netlogo, coordinate-systems

strange, a [question which I thought I had responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842474/netlogo-re-transformation-of-turtle-xcor-ycor-to-real-world-coords) and actually no!

All my GIS datas are well load in netlogo ! The layers are well aligned but xcor and ycor of agents are false false in light of the real world coordinates (e.i. img).

[image]

During sensibility analyse I whant than agents write their coordinated in a text file because I doesn't whant to deal with hundreds of shapefiles, so need to have the true GIS xcor and ycor in my agents.

My code :

```
  set buildings gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/bati2_wgs84.shp"
  set water gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/water_wgs84.shp"
  set bounds gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/bounds.shp"
  set quartier-gis gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/zones.shp"
  set loisir-gis gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/loisir.shp"

  set guest_house gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/auberges_wgs_class.shp"
  set doors gis:load-dataset "../data_gis/portes_wgs84.shp"

  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of bounds) ;; limite l'espace à l'enveloppe

  ;;Tracer les batiements
  gis:set-drawing-color black 
  gis:draw buildings 1

  ;;Tracer l'eau
  gis:set-drawing-color 129 ;violet 
  gis:draw quartier-gis 1 
  gis:apply-coverage quartier-gis "ZONE" my-quartier-p


  ;; pour chaque vecteur dans la base on charge les auberges
  foreach gis:feature-list-of guest_house [
    let location gis:location-of (first
      (first (gis:vertex-lists-of ?)))
    ;; on créée une turtle à chaque position d’un point et on lui copie ses attributs
    create-auberges 1 [
      set shape "circle"
      set xcor item 0 location
      set ycor item 1 location
;      set id gis:property-value ? "id"
      set nom gis:property-value ? "nom_auberg"
      set size 4
      set nb_chambres nb_chambres_init
      ;set standing random-normal 5 3
      set standing gis:property-value ? "standing"
      set class-standing gis:property-value ? "class"
      set color scale-color red standing 0 10
    ]]
```

So I need a hand ! 
thank you all

Comment: I'm not an expert in handling the NetLogo GIS extension. But have you tried using `show gis:envelope-of turtle 0`? As long as you go turtle by turtle you should get the transformed coordinates for each turtle. At least the NetLogo Dictionary states, that this primitive also works with single agents and agentsets.