# retrieve geographic coordinates of patches Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have a couple of rasters projected in Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area. I have integrated them into NetLogo as follows:

```
gis:set-world-envelope-ds (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of raster1)
                                                   (gis:envelope-of raster2))
```

Is there any way to retrieve the actual geographic coordinates from a turtle position instead of the NetLogo coordinates? When I use pxcor and pxcor I get the pixel coordinates from the NetLogo system starting from (0, 0) at the low left corner.

Thank you for your help

Comment: See also this question and comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665692/netlogo-gis-extension-how-to-have-right-xcor-and-ycor-from-turtles